# Waiting for two separate promises to resolve so state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

So I'm testing a react component button click that changes a state.  When rendering the component I need a promise to resolve so the button is rendered and thus clickable.  I accomplish this by placing the button click inside of a setTimeout as the component states get updated.  However after clicking the button a component state needs to be updated due to a promise being resolved.  I'll give an example below

```
class App extends component {
     constructor(props){
     this.state ={
         hasError = false;
         loading = true;
   }
}

componentdidMount(){
    this.apiGetFunc();

apiGetFunc(){
  this.setState({hasError: false});
  this.setState({loading = false});
}

onClickFunc{
   this.middleWareCalltoAPI.then(
      respone =>{ this.setState({hasError: false})},
      errorRespone =>{ this.setState({hasError = true})};
   )
}


renderer(){
   return (
     <Card>
     {!this.state.hasError && !this.state.loading && (
     <div>
     <Button>
        onClick = {this.onClickfunc}
     </Button>
     </div>
     </Card>
     )}
   )
}
```

Now here is what my test looks like

```
test("Save user permissions", done => {
  mock.onGet("anAPI.php").reply(200, mockData); //THIS IS NEEDED TO RENDER THE BUTTON
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

  setTimeout(() => {
    wrapper.find("Button").simulate("click"); //THIS CLICK SHOULD CHANGE hasError to true
    expect(wrapper.state.hasError).toEqual(true) //THIS FAILS
    done();
  }, 0);
});
```

I've tried nesting setTimeouts so the promise from the click can resolve but that doesn't seem to work.  I tried to pare down my code as much as possible so it's readable.  Let me know if you need me to provide more context.

EDIT: Made the code more closely resemble what I actually have

Comment: It is easiest to answer a question that has a minimum complete working example, if you can provide one that would be great.  In general testing async code with Promises works best when they are returned from functions under test and `await`-able.

Comment: I'm headed to a meeting but when I'm done I'll add something that is working code

Comment: updated the code to what I hope is a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your example code above that I'd highly suggest you invest some time in doing some simple React tutorials before attempting to move forward.

Nevertheless, here's a working example...

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/xj53m8lwvz (you can run the test by clicking the `Tests` tab near the bottom-left of the screen)

**api/fakeAPI.js**

```
const data = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: "delectus aut autem",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 3,
    title: "fugiat veniam minus",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 4,
    title: "et porro tempora",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 5,
    title: "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    completed: false
  }
];

export const fakeAPI = {
  failure: () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject("No data was found!");
      }, 1000);
    }),
  success: () =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(data);
      }, 1000);
    })
};
```

**components/App/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ShowData from "../ShowData/showData";
import ShowError from "../ShowError/showError";
import { fakeAPI } from "../../api/fakeAPI";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    hasError: "",
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchData();
  };

  fetchData = () => {
    fakeAPI
      .success()
      .then(data => this.setState({ isLoading: false, data: data }))
      .catch(err => this.setState({ isLoading: false, hasError: err }));
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true, data: [] }, () => {
      fakeAPI
        .failure()
        .then(res => this.setState({ isLoading: false, hasError: "" }))
        .catch(err => this.setState({ isLoading: false, hasError: err }));
    });
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="app-container">
      {this.state.isLoading ? (
         <ShowLoading />
      ) : this.state.hasError ? (
        <ShowError error={this.state.hasError} />
      ) : (
        <ShowData data={this.state.data} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**components/App/__test__/App.test.js** (`mountWrap` is a custom function you can find in `test/utils/index.js` and [WaitForExpect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-for-expect) is an easier way to wait for an assertion to be `true` within jest's default 5 second timeout)

```
import React from "react";
import { mountWrap } from "../../../test/utils";
import WaitForExpect from "wait-for-expect";
import App from "../App";

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  hasError: "",
  isLoading: true
};

const wrapper = mountWrap(<App />, initialState);
describe("App", () => {
  it("renders without errors", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("div.app-container")).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("initally shows that it's loading", () => {
    expect(wrapper.state("isLoading")).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find("div.loading")).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("renders data and shows an Update button", async () => {
    await WaitForExpect(() => {
      wrapper.update();
      expect(wrapper.state("isLoading")).toBeFalsy();
      expect(wrapper.find("div.data")).toHaveLength(5);
      expect(wrapper.find("button.update")).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });

  it("shows an error once the button has been clicked", async () => {
    wrapper.find(".update").simulate("click");
    await WaitForExpect(() => {
      wrapper.update();
      expect(wrapper.state("isLoading")).toBeFalsy();
      expect(wrapper.state("hasError")).toBe("No data was found!");
      expect(wrapper.find("div.error")).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a shot. Apologies for the code. I'm a month into a QA internship and it's my first time working with React. I'll be sure to check out some more tutorials though.

Comment: You bet. I'd highly recommend investing some time and money into this tutorial: https://www.udemy.com/react-2nd-edition/. This particular teacher does a great job at explaining React.